# Injection of annotated generic classes with Guice

Tags: java, generics, guice

I'm trying to inject different versions of the same generic type, so far with no luck. The bindings that I do in the AbstractModule implementation are:

```
   bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>>() {
}).annotatedWith(Names.named("name0")).toProvider(
    ConcurrentHashMap::new).in(Singleton.class);
   bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>>() {
}).annotatedWith(Names.named("name1")).toProvider(
    ConcurrentHashMap::new).in(Singleton.class);
   bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>>() {
}).annotatedWith(Names.named("name2")).toProvider(
    ConcurrentHashMap::new).in(Singleton.class);
   bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Short>>() {
}).annotatedWith(Names.named("name3")).toProvider(
    ConcurrentHashMap::new).in(Singleton.class);
```

I tried injecting them by simply using:

```
@Inject @Named("name0") ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>;
```

and so on. However, I get the following error:

> 1) Unable to create binding for
>   `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Integer>` annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=name0). It was already configured
>   on one or more child injectors or private modules

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This looks okay to me, can you try to [edit] to post a more complete [mcve] please?

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine, and the error message is pretty clear: Check your child injectors and your private modules for any other bindings to `@Named("name0") ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>`. Guice is very careful not to allow bindings for the same key in the same injector, even if the bindings are inaccessible directly from the parent injector due to child injectors or private modules.

You might also consider switching `toProvider` syntax for

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>>() {
}).annotatedWith(Names.named("name0")).toProvider(
ConcurrentHashMap::new).in(Singleton.class);
```

to the simpler use of `to`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>>() {})
   .annotatedWith(Names.named("name0"))
   .to(ConcurrentHashMap.class)
   .in(Singleton.class);
```

...partially because it's more typical of Guice usage, and partially because it may allow Guice to be more permissive with duplicate bindings. (Guice might have a hard time detecting duplicates through the Java 8 translation from `ConcurrentHashMap::new` to `Provider<ConcurrentHashMap>`.) Diagnosing the duplicate binding is probably a better idea, though.

Comment: Your suggestion actually doesn't compile, I get:
(argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>)

Comment: I have no child injectors: only a single AbstractModule implementation, with the bindings that appear in the original question

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem is with the injector itself. When I use the "Regular" Guice injector (by calling `Guice.createInjector(new MyModule())` everything works fine. However, I've been using the netflix governator injector (by calling `LifecycleInjector.builder().withModules(new MyModule()).build().createInjector()`), which seems to be causing the problem.